# Understanding linux clk_core clock topology

Tags: linux, drivers, hardware, clock

While reading linux [driver-api/clk.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/clk.html) documentation, I found, that `struct clk_core` has pointers to

```
struct clk_core         *parent;
```

I cannot understand, why tree topology is needed? Why just array is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Some clocks are based on others; for example in [`at91`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/drivers/clk/at91/clk-audio-pll.c#L9):

> The Sama5d2 SoC has two audio PLLs (PMC and PAD) that shares the same parent
>    (FRAC). FRAC can output between 620 and 700MHz and only multiply the rate of
>    its own parent. PMC and PAD can then divide the FRAC rate to best match the
>    asked rate.

In such setups, knowing the topology is important, because it determines the characteristics of a number of clocks.

Other clocks are multiplexers (*e.g.* in [`action`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/clk/actions/owl-mux.c)), and there again the topology is significant.